# Comparação de dados após nextLine java

Tags: java

Não estou conseguindo fazer minha estrutura de verificação funcionar, não consigo após digitar pare, exiba a mensagem e o programa continue o `loop`.

/*
     * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
     * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
     * and open the template in the editor.
     */
    package javaapplication4;

```
/**
 *
 * @author Deny
 */
import java.util.Scanner;

public class JavaApplication4 {

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
       String resposta;
       String r;
       String respostaVerificadora;
       String[] camgirls = new String[50000];
       Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

       //cadastro de cam girls
       for(int c=0; c < 50000; c++) {
           System.out.println("Digite o nome da camgirl de numero: "+c);
          //ISSO AQUI NAO TA FUNCIONANDO EU DIGITO PARE AQUI
           resposta = scan.next();
           //PARA DAR IGUAL AQUI
           respostaVerificadora = "pare";
     //E NA HORA DE VERIFICAR QUE OS DOIS SAO IGUAIS, O JAVA NAO RECONHECE E NAO ENTRA NO IF
           if(resposta == respostaVerificadora ) {
               System.out.println("parei");
               break;
           }

       }
        System.out.println("PROGRAMA FINALIZADO");
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Java não possui sobrecarga de operadores, quando você compara objetos usando `==`, Java compara a referência desses objetos.
Mesmo que o valor das strings sejam iguais, as referências são diferentes, para comparar os valores você precisa usar o método equals.

```
resposta.equals(respostaVerificadora)
```

Sugiro também você procurar aprender como utilizar o List do Java, porque criar arrays de 50000 variáveis é absurdamente ineficiente.